# Handeling SSL Client not reading all data

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl, server

I am trying to accomplish, that my ssl server does not break down, <s>when a client does not collect all data.</s>  (fixed with one minor bug)
when the data is too long.

Basically what I'm trying to do is write in a non-blocking way. *For that I found two different approaches:*

**First approach**
using this code

```
int flags = fcntl(ret.fdsock, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(ret.fdsock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

and creating the ssl connection with it

**Second approach:**
Doing this directly after creating the SSL Object using `SSL_new(ctx)`

```
BIO *sock = BIO_new_socket(ret.fdsock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
BIO_set_nbio(sock, 1);
SSL_set_bio(client, sock, sock);
```

Both of which have their downsides, but neither of which helps solving the problem.
The first approach seems to read in a unblocking way just fine, but when I write more data, than the client reads, my server crashes.
The second approach does not seem to do anything, so my guess is, that I did something wrong or did not understand what a BIO actually does.

For more Information here is how the server writes to the client:

```
int SSLConnection::send(char* msg, const int size){
    int rest_size = size;
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    char* begin = msg;
    std::cout << "expected bytes to send: " << size << std::endl;
    while(rest_size > 0) {
        int tmp_bytes_sent = SSL_write(connection, begin, rest_size);
        std::cout << "any error     : " << ERR_get_error()<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "tmp_bytes_sent: " << tmp_bytes_sent << std::endl;
        if (tmp_bytes_sent < 0){
            std::cout << tmp_bytes_sent << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ssl error     : " << SSL_get_error(this->connection, tmp_bytes_sent)<< std::endl;
        } else {
            bytes_sent += tmp_bytes_sent;
            rest_size -= tmp_bytes_sent;
            begin = msg+bytes_sent;
        }
    }
    return bytes_sent;
}
```

**Output:**

```
expected bytes to send: 78888890
Betätigen Sie die <RETURN> Taste, um das Fenster zu schließen...
(means: hit <return> to close window)
```

***EDIT:*** After people said, that I need to cache errors appropriate, here is my new code:

**Setup:**

```
connection = SSL_new(ctx);
if (connection){
    BIO * sbio = BIO_new_socket(ret.fdsock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    if (sbio) {
        BIO_set_nbio(sbio, false);
        SSL_set_bio(connection, sbio, sbio);
        SSL_set_accept_state(connection);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Bio is null" << std::endl;
    }
} else {
    std::cout << "client is null" << std::endl;
}
```

**Sending:**

```
int SSLConnection::send(char* msg, const int size){
    if(connection == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERR: Connection is NULL" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int rest_size = size;
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    char* begin = msg;
    std::cout << "expected bytes to send: " << size << std::endl;
    while(rest_size > 0) {
        int tmp_bytes_sent = SSL_write(connection, begin, rest_size);
        std::cout << "any error     : " << ERR_get_error()<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "tmp_bytes_sent: " << tmp_bytes_sent << std::endl;
        if (tmp_bytes_sent < 0){
            std::cout << tmp_bytes_sent << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ssl error     : " << SSL_get_error(this->connection, tmp_bytes_sent)<< std::endl;
            break;
        } else if (tmp_bytes_sent == 0){
            std::cout << "tmp_bytes are 0" << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
            bytes_sent += tmp_bytes_sent;
            rest_size -= tmp_bytes_sent;
            begin = msg+bytes_sent;
        }
    }

    return bytes_sent;
}
```

*Using a client, that fetches 60 bytes, here is the output:*

**Output writing 1,000,000 Bytes:**

```
expected bytes to send: 1000000
any error     : 0
tmp_bytes_sent: 16384
any error     : 0
tmp_bytes_sent: 16384
Betätigen Sie die <RETURN> Taste, um das Fenster zu schließen...
(translates to: hit <RETURN> to close window)
```

**Output writing 1,000 bytes:**

```
expected bytes to send: 1000
any error     : 0
tmp_bytes_sent: 1000
connection closed  <- expected output
```

Comment: No sadly there is no -1, that the point. That's just a temporary printout, which will be removed, as soon as I get the error return. Crashing means crashing. The Server just stops. Like a segfault, but without displaying it.

Comment: A crash is an unexpected exit. Is that what you mean? It seems far more likely to me that you don't have a crash but an infinite loop. See my answer. NB Error-reporting code is never 'temporary', and must always show the actual error, not just the -1 symptom.

Comment: "Betätigen Sie die <RETURN> Taste, um das Fenster zu schließen...". Translation please. This site is conducted in English.

Comment: sorry, just means "hit <return> to close window", it's QtCreator output ;)

Comment: Is it broken pipe? have you setup your signal handler?

Comment: @Calvin: Perfect! This was the problem. I just added signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) and it worked perfectly. Didn't thought, that this was the problem.

Comment: You don't need to 'cache errors appropriately', or indeed at all, but you do need to *catch* them.

Answer (score 2):

First, a warning:  non-blocking I/O over SSL is a rather baroque API, and it's difficult to use correctly.  In particular, the SSL layer sometimes needs to read internal data before it can write user data (or vice versa), and the caller's code is expected to be able to handle that based on the error-codes feedback it gets from the SSL calls it makes.  It can be made to work correctly, but it's not easy or obvious -- you are *de facto* required to implement a state machine in your code that echoes the state machine inside the SSL library.

Below is a simplified version of the logic that is required (it's extracted from the Write() method in [this file](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/SSLSocketDataIO.cpp) which is part of [this library](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/), in case you want to see a complete, working implementation)

```
enum {
   SSL_STATE_READ_WANTS_READABLE_SOCKET   = 0x01,
   SSL_STATE_READ_WANTS_WRITEABLE_SOCKET  = 0x02,
   SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_READABLE_SOCKET  = 0x04,
   SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_WRITEABLE_SOCKET = 0x08
};

// a bit-chord of SSL_STATE_* bits to keep track of what 
// the SSL layer needs us to do next before it can make more progress
uint32_t _sslState = 0;

// Note that this method returns the number of bytes sent, or -1
// if there was a fatal error.  So if this method returns 0 that just
// means that this function was not able to send any bytes at this time.
int32_t SSLSocketDataIO :: Write(const void *buffer, uint32 size)
{
   int32_t bytes = SSL_write(_ssl, buffer, size);
   if (bytes > 0) 
   {
      // SSL was able to send some bytes, so clear the relevant SSL-state-flags
      _sslState &= ~(SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_READABLE_SOCKET | SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_WRITEABLE_SOCKET);
   }
   else if (bytes == 0) 
   {
      return -1;  // the SSL connection was closed, so return failure
   }
   else
   {
      // The SSL layer's internal needs aren't being met, so we now have to
      // ask it what its problem is, then give it what it wants.  :P
      int err = SSL_get_error(_ssl, bytes);
      if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
      {
         // SSL can't write anything more until the socket becomes readable,
         // so we need to go back to our event loop, wait until the
         // socket select()'s as readable, and then call SSL_Write() again.
         _sslState |=  SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_READABLE_SOCKET;
         _sslState &= ~SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_WRITEABLE_SOCKET;
         bytes = 0;  // Tell the caller we weren't able to send anything yet
      }
      else if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
      {
         // SSL can't write anything more until the socket becomes writable,
         // so we need to go back to our event loop, wait until the
         // socket select()'s as writeable, and then call SSL_Write() again.
         _sslState &= ~SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_READABLE_SOCKET;
         _sslState |=  SSL_STATE_WRITE_WANTS_WRITEABLE_SOCKET;
         bytes = 0;  // Tell the caller we weren't able to send anything yet
      }
      else
      {
         // SSL had some other problem I don't know how to deal with,
         // so just print some debug output and then return failure.
         fprintf(stderr,"SSL_write() ERROR!");
         ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
      }
   }
   return bytes;  // Returns the number of bytes we actually sent
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the example, but for some reason my code still doesn't work as expected. `SSL_write` does NOT return anything besides send data. It runs the loop a few times, and then just crashes the application. This is my major problem and I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is

rest_size -= bytes_sent;

You should do rest_size -= tmp_bytes_sent;

Also

```
if (tmp_bytes_sent < 0){
            std::cout << tmp_bytes_sent << std::endl;
           //its an error condition
          return bytes_sent;
        }
```

I dont know whether this will fix the issue, but the code you pasted has the above mentioned issues

Comment: Yes that's definitely one problem. Stupid me :D

Answer (score 1):

> When I write more data, than the client reads, my server crashes.

No it doesn't, unless you've violently miscoded something else that you haven't posted here. It either loops forever or it gets an error: probably `ECONNRESET`, which means the client has behaved as you described, and you've detected it, so you should close the connection and forget about him. Instead of which, you are just looping forever, trying to send the data to a broken connection, which can never happen.

And when you get an error, there's not much use in just printing a -1. You should print the error, with `perror()` or `errno` or `strerror()`.

Speaking of looping forever, don't loop like this. `SSL_write()` can  return 0, which you aren't handling at all: this will cause an infinite loop. See also David Schwartz's comments below.

NB you should definitely use the second approach. OpenSSL needs to know that the socket is in non-blocking mode.

> Both of which have their downsides

Such as?

And as noted in the other answer,

```
rest_size -= bytes_sent;
```

should be

```
rest_size -= tmp_bytes_sent;
```

Comment: Since `tmp_bytes_sent` never went negative, I didn't see the point of doing that. See update of the question with the outputs I added.

Comment: You may not see the point of calculating `rest_size` correctly, but I do.

Comment: Your information about what to do when `SSL_write()` returns -1 is totally incorrect. For just one way this can go wrong, imagine if `SSL_write()` returns `-1` with `EAGAIN` because the server needs to *read* some renegotiation information from the other side before it can encrypt and send. The socket will already be writable, so waiting for it to become writable is incorrect. You should *never* try to "look through" the SSL black box and infer what has to happen on the socket from what has to happen on the SSL connection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That would cause `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ,` not `EAGAIN.` `EAGAIN` comes from the operating system because the socket send buffer is full. It has nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why? The only issue is that the socket send buffer is full. The only solution to that is to `select()` etc. SSL doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @EJP `EAGAIN` can come from the operating system because the socket send buffer is full or because the socket receive buffer is empty. That's why you have to call `SSL_get_error` to get the status of the SSL connection, which may be `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`. As I said, acting on the basis of `errno` after `SSL_write` is wrong because you can't tell.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You are right IF and only if it would return -1. I just wanted to see, if it enters the errorhandeling part at any time, of cause I don't want to look into a magic glass ball to solve any error, but before I get to analyse it, I need this error ;)

Comment: @EJP The receive buffer could be empty when the SSL engine went to read renegotation data, setting `errno` to `EAGAIN`. You have no way to know what the SSL engine needs in order to make forward progress until you ask it.

Comment: Another update to the question, I added the new output and 3 lines of error printing, same reslult.    
Also added some new information.